# Trying to create auto-calculation for hours of in and out script for google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I created a script for my team in google sheets where they can click a button to clock in and another button to clock out.

However, I've been trying to create a script to auto-calculate the amount of hours they worked in that time frame and I'm not able to build it.

I inserted a drawing of a few blocks that says Bianca, In and Out. I assigned a script to each block for the script below.

This is the portion that is not working.

```
function onPunchOut (){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var finish = sheet.getRange("E"+lastRow).getValue();
  var hoursWorked = sheet.getRange("F"+lastRow);
}

if (finish === "Out") {
  hoursWorked.setFormulaR1C1('=R[0]C[-2]-R[-1]C[-2]');
  hoursWorked.setNumberFormat("H:mm");
}
```

Current code that works for clocking in and out:

```
function setValue(cellName, value) {
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(cellName).setValue(value);
}

function getValue(cellName){
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(cellName).getValue();
}

function getNextRow() {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getLastRow() + 1;
}

function setBianca() {
 setValue('L1' , 'Bianca');
}

function addRecord(a, b, c){
  var row = getNextRow();
  setValue('A' + row, a);
  setValue('D' + row, b);
  setValue('E' + row, c);
}

function punchInBianca(){
  addRecord(getValue('L1'), new Date(), 'In');
}

function punchOutBianca(){
  addRecord(getValue('L1'), new Date(), 'Out');
}
```

Expected results:

```
Name           Date/Time         In/Out   **Hours worked**
Bianca          4/25/2019 7:59:34   In     **3.15**
Bianca          4/25/2019 11:15:20  Out    **0.29**
Bianca          4/25/2019 11:44:44  In     **4.55**
```

Actual results: get script errors trying to get hours worked. Says cannot find variable "finish"

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that (as you know) `finish` is not defined.  This is because the variable is local inside of the function `onPunchOut()`, and your `if` statement can not directly gain access to the variable.  Variables have two different kinds of scope; you can learn more about them [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript).  To solve your problem, move the `if` statement inside of the closing bracket of `onPunchOut()`.

Answer (score 0):

That worked. Thanks!

```
function onPunchOut (){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var finish = sheet.getRange("E"+lastRow).getValue();
  var hoursWorked = sheet.getRange("F"+lastRow);
  if (finish === "Out") {
  hoursWorked.setFormulaR1C1('=R[0]C[-2]-R[-1]C[-2]');
  hoursWorked.setNumberFormat("H:mm");
  }
}
```